# Deploy to device: Installation failed: AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe8000050

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an app that I am building with MonoTouch on my PC. I get this error when using the deploy to device

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -installdev "/SVN/myapp/bin/iPhone/Release/my.app"
Please ensure your device is connected...
Connected to: myiPad
This application has been signed with a provisioning profile which does not include any device
Connected to: myiPad
Installing application
Installation failed: AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe8000050
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

I have tried an iPhone 4 and iPad 2.

I am able to drag the my.app into either iTunes or iPhone configuration utility and install it with no error on either device. It then runs as expected.

Comment: Try changing the signing options in the project's properties (iPhone Bundle Signing page). In particular it's usually best to set Identity to Developer (Automatic) - but try the other options available if the automatic one doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is this:

```
This application has been signed with a provisioning profile which 
does not include any device
```

Rebuild your provisioning profile to include your device.  You can do this by plugging your device and from XCode selecting "Use this for development" in the organizer.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can get the same error, but with a different error code if the application is installed already, signed with a different certificate.  For example, if its installed with a testing distribution certificate, or other root certificate.

I have personal and work signing keys and this bites me every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my path was /Src/C#/App....  The deploy fails if you have a # char in your local path...

-C

Comment: Signatures are bad form. Please refer to the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your COM app id under the apple developer portal and then generate a provisioning profile for your device. Only then you can run on your device. Also make sure the corrospond your app id with the one you've set in your config.xml file.