# xamarin iOS update: Unknown Secure Transport error `ClosedGraceful'

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I updated Xamarin Studio to version n. 6. All is working well apart from when I call API. I read these links

- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68358/stable-release-cycle-7-feature-release
- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41206

I downloaded an old version of Xamarin Studio and Mono and now... I can't deploy my app on my iPad with the following error:

> error MT1006: Could not install the application
>   '/Users/enricorossini/Projects/myInspection/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/build-ipad2.5-9.3.2/myInspection.iOS.app'
>   on the device 'iPad di Enrico': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle
>   returned: 0xe8000087 (kAMDIncorrectArchitectureError).

and I receive the same error when I call the API. I read [Deploy to device: Installation failed: AMDeviceInstallApplication returned: 0xe8000050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712307/deploy-to-device-installation-failed-amdeviceinstallapplication-returned-0xe8) but it doesn't work.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

For other developers. The problem was in the request with HTTPS. If you use HTTP your webapi call is working fine. Meanwhile we're waiting a fix from Xamarin :)

Thanks